# How to open a gz file on pandas?

Tags: unicode, gzip, decode

I tried to open a file with gz extension using pandas like this
df=pd.read_csv('mutation.gz', compression='gzip')

and still got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 2561: invalid start byte
```

I keep getting this error no matter what I try.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this has nothing to do with the decompression. The decompressed data is not valid UTF-8, which is the default encoding.

You might try a [different encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), or a [different way to handle encoding errors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers).